# How to send and receive SMS in java?

Tags: java, java-me, sms, sms-gateway, smslib

I want my Java application to send and receive **SMS** without using any additional hardware devices and it must be free.

I made my search but all i found is titles, i found somethings like **SMSLib** but at the other hand i didn't find tutorials or books to learn that.

I also found that **SMSLib** code but didn't understand:

**Send Message/SMS Code**

```
package SMSEngine;
import org.smslib.*;
class SendMessage
{
public static void sendMessage(String number, String message)
{ 
CService srv = new CService("COM4",9600,"huawei","E220");
try
{
srv.setSimPin("0000");
srv.setSimPin2("0000");
srv.setSmscNumber("");
srv.connect();
COutgoingMessage msg = new COutgoingMessage(number, message); 
msg.setMessageEncoding(CMessage.MessageEncoding.Enc7Bit);
msg.setStatusReport(true);
msg.setValidityPeriod(8);
srv.sendMessage(msg);
srv.disconnect();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
System.exit(0);
}
}
```

**Read Message/SMS Codes**

```
package SMSEngine;
import org.smslib.*;
import java.util.*;
class ReadMessages
{
static CService srv;
public static LinkedList receiveMessage()
{
LinkedList msgList = new LinkedList();
/*
To Check COM port Go in following path in Windows7
Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Bluetooth and Local COM

*/
srv = new CService("COM4",9600,"huawei","E220");//"COM1", 57600, "Nokia", ""
try
{
srv.setSimPin("0000");
srv.setSimPin2("0000");
srv.connect();
srv.readMessages(msgList, CIncomingMessage.MessageClass.Unread);
srv.disconnect();
return msgList;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
System.exit(0);
return msgList;
}
}
```

Comment: Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow!

Comment: @AndrewThompson this is not my code, as i said i just found it when searching

Comment: You are obviously searching in the wrong places.  Avoid roseindia (or any other site that cannot manage to display indented code) like you might avoid the plague..

Comment: well, so you recommend me anything?

Comment: No, not really anything beyond what I have already put in comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to send SMS messages you have two options: either use a gateway modem, or use a bulk service with an online API.

SMSLib is only a library that makes it *easier* to interface with a gateway (hardware device) or with a bulk SMS provider. Either way, the library by itself is not enough.

The code sample that you provided appears to try to use a gateway connected to a local serial port but since you don't have such a hardware device it's not going to work for you.

Comment: So, what about using a service? what you recommend for me in that?

Comment: I don't have experience with online services for sending SMS messages. But if you'd like to play around with a hardware gateway I've used Moxa OnCell before and it's pretty simple to get going..

Comment: but it's a generic application and i can't use a special hardware to do that stage

Comment: I'm not saying you shouldn't use an online service, just that I haven't used one myself and so I can't make any recommendations as to which would be best or easiest to work with, or pricing-wise..

Comment: using a "USB Modem" as a gateway makes the job

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use [SMS gateway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SMS_gateways) and send them like ordinary emails.

Answer (score 1):

> "I also found that **SMSLib** code but didn't understand"-

Assuming that you know java/object oriented programming, read through an online tutorial on **smslib** for understanding the basics. May be you can start with this one  http://smslib.org/doc/smslib/quickstart/

Comment: as already answered by @MikyDinescu, the code sample is definitely using a hardware, probably a huawei E220 modem connected to COM4 port having 9600 baud rate.

Comment: i found that site before but i think it's a general talk, i want something learn me that theoretically and programmaticly